# Python Microframework Bottle not working

Tags: python, opencv, request, bottle

```
from bottle import route, run, get, request, static_file
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
from skimage import data
from skimage import io
from PIL import Image

def imageProcessing(image):
    img = io.imread(image)
    img = rgb2gray(img)
    io.imsave('sr.png', img)
    im = Image.open(static_file('sr.png', root='sr.png'))
    bg = Image.new("L", im.size, "white")
    print "made bg"
    bg.paste(im)
    txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(bg)
    return txt

@get('/a')
def test():
    url = request.get('url')
    if url:
        text = imageProcessing(url)       
        return {"url": url, "txt": text, "entities": arrayOfEntities}
    else:
        return {"url": url}

run(host='localhost', port=8080, reloader=True)
```

Can anyone explain to me why this isn't working? I don't think there is anything off with the code, I've been working on this for hours. I could be wrong though.

Why does it always return "url": null? How can I make it register the URL?

Thanks very much.

Comment: how do you call up your webpage? `http://localhost:8080/a?url=xyz`?

Comment: @Daniel yeah that's what I do

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `request.GET`:

```
@get('/a')
def test():
    url = request.GET.get('url')
    if url:
        text = imageProcessing(url)       
        return {"url": url, "txt": text, "entities": arrayOfEntities}
    else:
        return {"url": url}
```